# SSIS - Can't open Excel file in protected view

Tags: excel, ssis

I'm running into a strange issue when trying to load excel spreadsheets into my database through SSIS (2012).

I'm getting the spreadsheets (which are xlsx files) via email, and then I manually save them to my local drive (C:\temp). When I try to use the excel file as a source in SSIS, I am not able to pick any excel sheets in the book.

The file is not corrupted, not open on my machine, and not password protected. It is, however, opening in Protected View. So I go into Excel and turned off all the Protected View options, but no cigar. The only way I am able to use the file as an excel source in SSIS is by opening it, and saving over it.

Does anyone have a similar experience? Other than opening and saving all of the files manually, is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue with xml based excel (xlsx). If you can save them as xls, that will solve the problem. If for some reason that's not possible you may need to use OLE source to read them.