# How to read Excel file in SSIS package with Enable Protected View for files originating from the internet

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, protected

I have an SSRS reports form where in Export my results in Excel file. As Excel behavior is to Enable Protected View for files originating from the internet. it asks for Enable Editing button clicked or setting off for Excel.

i am using script task C# to read excel in SSIS. but to execute it, i need to click on enable editing on in Excel. is there any way to not to set the settings or open the file to make it writable. my script task works in development but fails in deploy mode. below is the code. please help me to figure out.

```
            //pass that to workbook object  
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath);

            foreach (Worksheet worksheet in workBook.Worksheets)
            {
                if (worksheet.Name.Equals(sheetName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = worksheet.UsedRange;
                    object[,] data = new object[xlRange.Rows.Count - 1, xlRange.Columns.Count];
                    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

                    for (int i = 1; i <= xlRange.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 1; j <= xlRange.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            data[i - 1, j - 1] = (xlRange.Cells[i, j] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value;
                        }
                    }

                    workBook.Close(true);
                    oExcel.Application.Quit();
                    oExcel.Quit();
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBook);
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oExcel);

                    dt = ArraytoDatatable(data);
                    dt.TableName = tableName;
                    //BulkLoadDataTable(dt, connectionString);

                }
                else
                {
                    FireError("Wrong Sheet name found. Please Rename the sheet name as:" + sheetName);
                }
            }
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570472/ssis-cant-open-excel-file-in-protected-view